# @WebFilter( UrlPatterns = {""}) игнорируется

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlet

Я чего то не понимаю, как должны работать `urlPatterns` в фильтре?
Почему независимо от урла фильтр срабатывает в любом случае ?

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = {"/groups/*"})
public class AuthorizationFilter implements Filter {

    @Autowired
    UserService service;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;   

        filterChain.doFilter(request,servletResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}

....
    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        return new Filter[] { characterEncodingFilter,new AuthorizationFilter()};
    }
....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@WebFilter` - это аннотация не Spring, поэтому Spring её просто игнорирует. Без  `DispatcherServletInitializer` с методом `getServletFilters` web-приложение даже не заметит фильтров. Но `getServletFilters()` возвращает просто массив фильтров, без привязки к URL. А значит срабатывать они будут на любой запрос. Есть несколько выходов из этой ситуации.

Во-первых, можно прописывать соответствие адресов фильтрам в web.xml:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>authFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.example.AuthorizationFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>authFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/groups/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Во-вторых, можно использовать родные для Spring [HandlerInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html). Правда, код они не упростят. Придётся либо прописывать привязки уже не в дескрипторе развёртывания, а в конфигурации контекста, что не избавляет от xml и не упрощает его, либо конфигурировать их в коде:

```
public class AuthorizationInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {
        // Логика
    }
}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example")
@EnableWebMvc  
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry
          .addInterceptor(new AuthorizationInterceptor())
          .addPathPatterns("/groups/*");
    }
}

public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {  
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();  
        ctx.register(AppConfig.class);  
        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);    
        Dynamic dynamic = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));  
        dynamic.addMapping("/");  
        dynamic.setLoadOnStartup(1);  
   }  
}
```

Но можно этот вариант немного упростить с помощью изобретения велосипеда на аннотациях:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface AuthRequired {}

public class AuthorizationInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter { 
    @Override 
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception { 
        HandlerMethod hm = (HandlerMethod) handler; 
        Method method = hm.getMethod();
        if (method.getDeclaringClass().isAnnotationPresent(Controller.class)) {
            if (method.isAnnotationPresent(AuthRequired.class)) { 
                // Логика
            }
        } 
        return true; 
    }
}

@Controller
public class SimpleController {
    @RequestMapping(path = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        // Логика
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/groups/{groupName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @AuthRequired
    public String group(@PathVariable String groupName) {
        // Логика
    }
}
```

Остаётся прописать интерцептор в конфигурации контекста

```
<beans>
  <mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="com.example.AuthorizationInterceptor" />
  </mvc:interceptors>
</beans>
```

И он будет срабатывать только для методов помеченных соответствующей аннотацией. С этим велосипедом дескриптор развёртывания и конфигурация контекста предельно простые, а инициализатор вообще не нужен.

Впрочем, можно и вообще свой аналог анотации `@WebFilter` нагородить! Для начала нам понадобиться очередной велосипед для проверки паттернов:

```
public class GlobMatcher {
    public static boolean match(String pattern, String text) {
        String rest = null;
        int pos = pattern.indexOf('*');
        if (pos != -1) {
            rest = pattern.substring(pos + 1);
            pattern = pattern.substring(0, pos);
        }

        if (pattern.length() > text.length())
            return false;

        for (int i = 0; i < pattern.length(); i++)
            if (pattern.charAt(i) != '?' 
                    && !pattern.substring(i, i + 1).equalsIgnoreCase(text.substring(i, i + 1)))
                return false;

        if (rest == null) {
            return pattern.length() == text.length();
        } else {
            for (int i = pattern.length(); i <= text.length(); i++) {
                if (match(rest, text.substring(i)))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Своя аннотация WebFilter с тетрисом и программистками:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface WebFilter {
    String[] urlPatterns();
}
```

И немного видоизменённый интерцептор:

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = {"/groups/*"})
public class AuthorizationInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter { 
    @Override 
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception { 
        Class cls = getClass();
        if (cls.isAnnotationPresent(WebFilter.class)) {
            String[] patterns = ((WebFilter) cls.getAnnotation(WebFilter.class)).urlPatterns();
            for (String pattern : patterns) {
                if (GlobMatcher.match(pattern, request.getRequestURI())) {
                    // Логика
                }
            }
        }
        return true; 
    }
}
```

А чтобы не пачкать код сквозной функциональностью, можно для проверки соответствия текущего URL паттернам сделать аспект:

```
@Aspect
public class WebFilterAspect {
    @Pointcut("within(@com.example.WebFilter *)")
    public void beanAnnotatedWithWebFilter() {}

    @Pointcut("execution(boolean com.example..preHandle(..))")
    public void preHandleMethod() {}

    @Pointcut("preHandleMethod() && beanAnnotatedWithWebFilter()")
    public void preHandleMethodInsideAClassMarkedWithWebFilter() {}

    @Around("preHandleMethodInsideAClassMarkedWithWebFilter()")
    public Object beforeFilter(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
        if(args.length > 0) {
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) args[0];
            Class target = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass();
            if (target.isAnnotationPresent(WebFilter.class)) {
                String[] patterns = ((WebFilter) target.getAnnotation(WebFilter.class)).urlPatterns();
                for (String pattern : patterns) {
                    if (GlobMatcher.match(pattern, request.getRequestURI())) {
                        return joinPoint.proceed();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

И тогда интерцептор упрощается до:

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = {"/groups/*"})
public class AuthorizationInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter { 
    @Override 
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception { 
        // Логика
        return true; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для доступа к Spring Beans из Servlet можно создать класс обертку для `request`, являющимся наследником `HttpServletRequestWrapper`, из которого уже вызвать метод `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this)`.
(https://stackoverflow.com/a/17490865/9967010)

```
@WebFilter("/groups/*")
public class AuthorizationFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;   

        AuthenticatedRequest authenticatedRequest = new AuthenticatedRequest(request, response);

        if(foo(response) || authenticatedRequest.foo()) {
            filterChain.doFilter(authenticatedRequest, servletResponse);
        } else {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "error message");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

```
public class AuthenticatedRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    @Autowired
    UserService service;

    public AuthenticatedRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(request);

        if (service==null) {
           SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
        }
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
        return () -> service.getCurrentUserName();
    }
    ...
}
```